# Converting text log file with data in quotes to individual columns, using RegEx

Tags: regex, bash, csv, export-to-csv

I have a text log file and everything I want to capture within this file are in quotes (which are on separate lines).

```
"rows": [
    {"values": [
        "word",
        "120.134.12.43",
        "34780",
        "33.334.115.100",
        "9834-5202011",
        "221",
        "NYC-LOG-01.test",
        "something.test.com",
        "something.test.com\/",
        "internet-communications-and-telephony",
        "983439849389483",
        "unknown, United States"
    ]},
    {"values": [
        "ssl",
        "20.311.3.21",
        "3443",
        "40.51.96.219",
        "93140-9834811",
        "211",
        "nyc-log-01.test",
        "a.jones.com",
        "a.jones.com\/",
        "news",
        "3434231343434356",
        "Somewhere, California, United States, 12345"
```

I want to capture this data after but not including when the line says "values" the first row says "rows" but this does not appear again. I would like to export the file to a CSV file. Each txt file has 12 rows of data I want to capture but it would be nice if I could increase this too.

Comment: Ok thanks Paul, hope someone will assist, cheers C.

Comment: apologize, my output should be a csv. So that each item in quotes besides "values" & "rows" are in separate columns on one line. The purpose is so i can sort out categories such as news etc thanks again i really appreciate the support.

Comment: Sorry inian i dont understand what you are saying. Why is my input incomplete? There is some lines at the start of this but it dont see how that is relevant as i want the regex to only look for items in quotes as per the data and put these 12 items into one row, one item per column. I would like to use terminal .sh regEx's to complete this task. Am i making sense? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```py
import csv
import json

with open('data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

with open("test.csv", "wb+") as output_file:
    f = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "wb+"))

    for entry in data['rows']:
        f.writerow(entry['values'])
```

You are converting your data from JSON to CSV. Be aware that JSON is already a very easily parsed format, so this conversion is not necessarily needed or even a good idea.

Assuming your input is called **data.json**:

```
{"rows": [
    {"values": [
        "word",
        "120.134.12.43",
        "34780",
        "33.334.115.100",
        "9834-5202011",
        "221",
        "NYC-LOG-01.test",
        "something.test.com",
        "something.test.com\/",
        "internet-communications-and-telephony",
        "983439849389483",
        "unknown, United States"
    ]},
    {"values": [
        "ssl",
        "20.311.3.21",
        "3443",
        "40.51.96.219",
        "93140-9834811",
        "211",
        "nyc-log-01.test",
        "a.jones.com",
        "a.jones.com\/",
        "news",
        "3434231343434356",
        "Somewhere, California, United States, 12345"
    ]
}]}
```

Comment: Hi no i am just importing from a text file or maybe this is json format? ill try this in bash and see what happens. Apologize i am rusty on my programming so thank you again.

Comment: Bash, oh sorry I wrote Python!

Comment: The result when i run this in terminal, on my MAC is the following "grep: empty (sub)expression"

Comment: I didn't read the tags on the question properly, sorry. The code above is Python. So if you want to run it, put in in a file called `program.py` and run `python program.py`.

Comment: Agh i need it in regex rather than python as that's a requirement as i am trying to learn Regx. If you can convert that would be amazing as id love to see it working thanks C.

Answer (score 0):

Your data looks like it is in JSON format? (you're missing the surrounding `{}`?). If so the simplest approach would be to use a parser such as `jq`

```
$ jq -r '.rows[].values | @csv' input-file
"word","120.134.12.43","34780","33.334.115.100","9834-5202011","221","NYC-LOG-01.test","something.test.com","something.test.com/","internet-communications-and-telephony","983439849389483","unknown, United States"
"ssl","20.311.3.21","3443","40.51.96.219","93140-9834811","211","nyc-log-01.test","a.jones.com","a.jones.com/","news","3434231343434356","Somewhere, California, United States, 12345"
```

Or you could use the `json` module that ships with Python

```
$ python -c 'import csv, json, sys; csv.writer(sys.stdout).writerows(row["values"] for row in json.load(sys.stdin)["rows"])' < filename
```

Finally a terrible approach (but does what you want for this particular input example) could be

```
sed -n '/^ *\(".*"\),*$/{ s/^ *//; H; }; /^ *\]/{ s/.*//; x; s/\n//g;  p; }' filename
```